# Dynamically adding forms, which can be inserted into a sql table

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, forms

Looking for a solution that will allow me to dynamically add another form, which on clicking "save" will individually be sent to SQL and saved as a row there.

For a better explanation of what I'm trying to achieve here is a picture: 
[image]

As you can see it's a simple form with 3 input fields.
Currently, if you click on "Opslaan" (Save), the data gets sent to the database and is saved. Here is the code:

```
<form style="margin-bottom: 50px;" action="(linktothephpfilelistedbelow" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Verkocht Product Toevoegen</legend>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="klantnummer">Klant nummer</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="textinput" name="klantnummer" type="text" placeholder="hier het klantnummer" class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="kledingstuk-nummer">Kledingstuk nummer</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="Kledingstuk-nummer" name="kledingstuk" type="text" placeholder="hier het nummer van het kledingstuk" class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="prijs">Prijs kledingstuk</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="Prijs" name="prijs" type="text" placeholder="hier de prijs van het kledingstuk" class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button (Double) -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="extraproduct"></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="extraproduct" type="submit" value="Opslaan" name="extraproduct" class="btn btn-success"></input>
                <button id="button2id" name="extraproduct" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
              </div>
            </div>

            </fieldset>
            </form>




<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysql_connect("blankforreasons");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

// Escape user inputs for security

$klant_nummer1 = $_POST['klantnummer'];
$artikel_nummer1 = $_POST['kledingstuk'];
$prijs1 = $_POST['prijs'];

$klant_nummer = mysql_real_escape_string($klant_nummer1);
$artikel_nummer = mysql_real_escape_string($artikel_nummer1);
$prijs = mysql_real_escape_string($prijs1);



// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO soldproducts (klantnummer, artikelnummer, prijs, tijd) VALUES ('$klant_nummer','$artikel_nummer', '$prijs', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

mysql_select_db('blankforreasons');

$retval = mysql_query ($sql, $link);

if(! $retval ) { 
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "<h2>Producten succesvol toegevoegd</h2>
    <a href='../producten'><button>klik hier om terug te gaan</button></a>";


// close connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

The function that I am trying to add is the ability to click the "+" button, adding a 2nd form (the same as the first one), then a 3rd, 4th, etc. So that my client is able to add multiple items at the same time to the database.

EDIT:

Just finished the code to dynamically add extra forms:

```
<script>
        var i = 1;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button2id").on('click', function () {
                i++;
                var data = "<legend>Product #"+i+"</legend><div class='form-group'><label class='col-md-4 control-label' for='klantnummer'>Klant nummer</label>  <div class='col-md-4'><input id='textinput' name='klantnummer' type='text' placeholder='hier het klantnummer' class='form-control input-md' required=''></div></div><div class='form-group'><label class='col-md-4 control-label' for='kledingstuk-nummer'>Kledingstuk nummer</label>  <div class='col-md-4'><input id='Kledingstuk-nummer' name='kledingstuk' type='text' placeholder='hier het nummer van het kledingstuk' class='form-control input-md' required=''></div></div><div class='form-group'><label class='col-md-4 control-label' for='prijs'>Prijs kledingstuk</label>  <div class='col-md-4'><input id='Prijs' name='prijs' type='text' placeholder='hier de prijs van het kledingstuk' class='form-control input-md' required=''></div></div>";
                $(".form-horizontal fieldset .inputfields").append(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Now I only need the ability to save every extra added form as a new record when clicking "Save".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I am using Jquery If you don't want to use jquery then you can find the alernative I am just trying to give idea to track your problem

```
    <script>
var i = 0;
     $('#btn2').on('click',function(){
          i =i+1;
       var html = '"<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="klantnummer">XYZ nummer</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="textinput'+i+'" name="klantnummer[]" type="text" placeholder="hier het klantnummer" class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>"';
       $('#appendUp').insertBefore(html) // Add a empty div where you want to append your html.

     });
    </script>
```

Now when the form will be submitted the new fields would be submitted with the form.

**UPDATE**

Suppose from your html you added a name input array and you want to store all the names in your database col 'name'.

you can use all your function to escape illegal char input,etc and at last implode the array to a string

```
<?php
 if(isset($_post('name')))
{
   $x = $post('name');
  $x = implode(',',$x);
}else{
$x = null;
}

//Now Save $x in your datatable if any extra coloumn are added then they would be stored or null will be stored.
?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

HTML

```
<input name = "productitem[0]" id= "productitem0"/> // this is your base form
```

Now when you add a  new input field with plus button

```
var html = '<input name = "productitem[]" id= "productitem'+i+'"/>';
```

Ok now you have a array sent to you php server with name productitem

```
<?php
 //use Foreach loop
$x =$_POST['productitem'];
$y =$_POST['articles'];
 foreach($x as $key => $data){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO soldproducts (klantnummer, artikelnummer, prijs, tijd) VALUES ('$x[$key]','$y[$key]', '$prijs[$key]', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

} 
?>
```

Comment: I just did something similar, am now able to dynamically add extra forms, just need to add the functionality to add those forms as records aswell

Comment: Okay so now I basically have: productitem, artikel, prijs, productitem2, artikel2, prijs2, etc as the $_post data, how do I go about to storing these as seperate records?

Comment: Thank you! This, indeed, was the answer I was looking for :) It's now functioning correctly.